# Using common samples to numerically estimate pairwise equality of three random variables

Tags: pr.probability, sampling

Let $X,Y,Z$ be three discrete random variables which I can numerically sample. I need to numerically estimate the probability that $X=Y$ and the probability that $X=Z$. I would like to know whether the algorithm that I describe below is suited to this goal. In particular, I would like to know whether it is acceptable to use the same samples from $X$ to estimate both quantities.

My current algorithm generates $n$ independent samples of each random variable. That is, I generate three vectors:
$$(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\\
 (y_1,\ldots,y_n)\\
(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$$
Associated to these vectors, I define two counting variables as follows,
$$c_{XY}:=\sum_{i=1}^n\displaystyle\delta_{x_iy_i}\qquad c_{XZ}:=\sum_{i=1}^n\delta_{x_iz_i} $$
where $\delta_{ij}$ is the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta).
Finally, I estimate my probabilities in the following way:
$$P(X=Y)\approx \frac{c_{XY}}{n}\qquad P(X=Z)\approx \frac{c_{XZ}}{n}$$.

I would greatly appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two estimators $c_{XY}/n$ and $c_{XZ}/n$ are unbiased estimators of $P(X=Y)$ and $P(X=Z)$ respectively.  They are not independent, however.  Whether that is "acceptable" might depend on what you're using them for.